# openAM authentication log

Tags: logging, logstash, openam

I am interested to find the login success and login failure for openAM (AM-eval-6.5.1/XUI/#login/). I have deployed it in apache tomcat localhost. Take an example if login failed due to wrong password.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The JSON-formatted audit log for authentication can be found in directory

```
AM_CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORY/AM_DEPLOYMENT_URI/log/authentication.audit.json
```